# Why jmeter generate other requests and put a number for them

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I have a script, one of the requests in the script is: redireccion.html, but when I generate the HTML Dashboard report I see:
redireccion.html-0, redireccion.html-1, redireccion.html-2

Why those requests are generated by Jmeter?

[HTML Dashboard Report Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPRzW.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when your first request i.e. `redireccion.html` encounters a [HTTP Redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections), i.e. gets a [Redirection Message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#Redirection_messages)

JMeter stores all these redirects as **sub-results**

[image]

If you don't want these `sub-results` to be present in the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) - you can run your test providing `jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults` property with the value of `false` like:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl -e -o dashboard
```

In order to make the change permanent - just add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
```

More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)